# invoke javascript on button click of a datatable row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Im using dataTable and I have the following:

```
 var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({

                bProcessing: true,
                sAjaxSource: "/Cart/addresses",
                'iDisplayLength': 5,
                aaSorting: [],
                aoColumns: [
                    { "mData": "Contact" },
                    { "mData": "Address" },
                    { "mData": "Postcode" },
                    {
                        "mData": null,
                        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success use-address" onclick="doFunction();" role="button" data-adcode="' + full.ADCode + '">' + 'Use Address' + '</button>';
                        }
                    }

                ]
            });
```

I have tried the following, i basically want to be bale to use adcode when the button is clicked:

```
 $('.use-address').click(function () {
        var adccode = $(this).data("adcode");

    });

    function doFunction()
    {
        var adccode = $(this).data("adcode");

    }
```

This wont work, in firebug it doesnt hit either of these.

Note the datatable is added dynamically (after clicking a button.)

Any ideas why it aint working?

Thanks

Comment: Where does full.ADCode come from? Show us some lines of your json data.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here:

```
$('#example').on('click','.use-address',function () {
    var adccode = $(this).data("adcode");
});
```

Comment: i can now enter the this function, but cant get hold of $(this).data("adcode"); which was a data- attribute on the link

Comment: Try to use `$(this).attr("data-adcode");` instead of `$(this).data("adcode");`

Comment: that didn't work either...  is there another way of invoking a method and passing adcode?